# Iptables doesn't allow network traffic from open ports

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall, linux-networking

I changed the policy of the INPUT chain, adding the following command.

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

After I inserted the next rules in order to allow input packets from the network ports 80 and 443 but the ports are still closed (e.g. I can't use web browser).

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Output from `iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

How could I allow network traffic from HTTP and HTTPS ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow incoming requests on ports 80 and 443 and that has been done using the two accept rules.

You need also to allow `ESTABLISHED` traffic, but this can be skipped in your because you are setting `OUTPUT` policy to `ACCEPT`.

Your rules seem to be enough for allowing incoming requests only. You will not be able to initiate connections to other machines. This is because you are denying all `INPUT` traffic (including `ESTABLISHED` connections). To fix this, you can add a rule like:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

In order to help debug your problem, you can try several things:

1. Use `tcpdump` to capture traffic to confirm where it is dropped.
2. Change `INPUT` policy to `ACCEPT` temporarily to confirm it is related to your firewall rules or not.
3. Using `iptables -L -n -v` to show the hits of each rule may help you confirm your rules are matching some traffic or not (while you are trying to access your allowed ports). This can be useful on a non-busy server only.
4. Use `LOG` target in iptables to log packets just before your accept rule to confirm the packet source/destination IP and ports match your expectation.